# How to distinguish between the convex and concave angle using e.g. ABC notation in explementary angles

Tags: geometry

It sounds innocent enough but I am stuck.
Suppose you have an ABC angle of 20 degrees. The "external" angle is 340 degrees.
If I call it ABC (with the ^ on the top of the B of course), then it refers to the 20 degrees.
But I have one slide in which I am explaining the explementary angles and... I don't know how to CALL the 340 degrees angle, since I have ABC and ABC simply refers to the 20 degrees angle.

Could it be that the ABC notation (with ^ on the B) is used only for angles < 180 degrees?
Regardless... How do you mathematically call the "other" angle, the concave one, once you draw an ABC angle of 20 degrees?

Comment: If you pick an orientation, you can say that the angle $\angle ABC$ is the angle in which the ray $BA$ rotates to the ray $BC$ in the positive orientation (The rays $BA$ and $BC$ form a positively oriented frame). It is common to choose the countercloclwise orientation as the positive one. The other angle would be $\angle CBA$.

Comment: Use notation of oriented angles, i.e., instead of writing $\angle ABC$, write $(\vec{BA},\vec{BC})= 20° + k 360°$. This avoids ambiguities.

Comment: Thank you all, but it's for 13 years old and so I was hoping for something a little less complicated than "positively oriented frame" and +kx360 :) :) :)